# Submitting form located within another form

Tags: javascript, html

Take a look at this html:

```
<head>
<title>Test page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm() {
        document.getElementById("form2").submit();
     }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="test1" value="test" />

    <form id="form2" name="form2" action="http://google.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="test2" value="nothing" />
    </form>
</form>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</a>
</body>
```

Thing I want to do is submitting form2 located within form1 with a javascript. I want this to be done by submitForm() function. The problem is that it doesn't appear to work. I'm using FireFox for testing and always get an error which says that it's undefined. Does anybody know how I can get it working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: nested form elements aren't valid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't nest HTML forms like that.  End form1 before starting form2.  Duplicate the hidden input if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Well, given that you have no element with the ID "xxx", I could see where your script might have some difficulty. Perhaps you mean "form2"?