# Form within another form - using Blueimp file uploader within another form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a sort of internal communication tool, where users can post comments and attach files.

I'm using the blue imp file uploader: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/

And I made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/denislexic/s56xG/12/

But to simplify, I made an extract here:

```
<form action="/path/to/submit/" method="post" style="padding:10px;">
    <textarea style="display:block; width:60%;"></textarea>


    <form id="fileupload" action="server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- Blue imp form stuff in here -->
    </form>


    <a href="#" class="btn JS_fileUpload">Attach file</a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```

The problem is that, design wise, I really need the Submit button to be after the textarea and file uploader, and the file uploader has to be in between...so that means I have to have nested forms (which doesn't doesn't work)? Is there another solution?

PS: I've seen this question, but doesn't seem relevant: [Submitting form located within another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603871/submitting-form-located-within-another-form)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Nested forms are invalid HTML, so you'll need to use some CSS to put things in an appropriate layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mess with CSS to move things into an appropriate position while maintaining valid HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#content0 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#content1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3ex;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
}
#sub0 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8ex;
  left: 0;
}
</style>

<div id="container">

<form>
  <div id="content0">
    <input name="foo">
    <input id="sub0" type="submit"> 
  </div>
</form>

<form>
  <div id="content1">
    <input name="bar">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit this bit"> 
  </div>
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: This will solve the issue while still supporting old browsers.. But not everyone needs to support old browser and this might break most website designs especially if they're responsive (as is most new designs). 
I'm going for Vatentin Despa's solution for design purposes (even though it'll drop some old browsers support).

Answer (score 3):

One easy way is not to use `<form>` but another element, like a `div`:

```
<div id="fileupload">
```

You need to update your script and set the `url` parameter:

```
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/uploadFile.php',
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Amazing! 
This is the correct answer. I've tried so many manipulations on the basic example (it puts the id="fileuplaod" on the file input and therefore you lose all of the BasicPlusUI example functionality) but this simple solution solves everything.